# Does the ordering and incorrect individual source formats affect playing html5 videos on iOS safari?

Tags: ios, html, mobile-safari, html5-video

Does the ordering of source formats matter within HMTL5 videos tags? Also, if 1 of the formats is incorrect won't all browsers just find the one they like and ignore the ones that are bad?

I can't understand why the following code won't work on iOS4.2 safari:

```
<video id="myVideo"  poster="/images/01.png" width="600" height="400" >
<source src="/uploads/12373/6/oceans-clip.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
<source src="/uploads/12373/6/oceans-clip.webM" type="video/webM" />
<source src="/uploads/12373/6/oceans-clip.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
<p>Your browser does not support the video tag.</p>
</video>

<div class="control">
<a href="#" class="btnPlay">Play/Pause</a>
</div>
```

On my iPhone in Safari, the play pause button works fine and it appears to load the video but then I get a popup saying "cannot play movie". The only things I can think of are that the .webM file doesn't actually exist (which is true, it doesn't, though the others do) or that I need to specify the .ogv before the .webM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand the browser tries the sources in order, so your example would attempt mp4 first, them .webM and finally the .ogv file.

If the webM file doesn't exist then that is your problem. The browser is compatible with the webM format, attempts to get the file, then gets a 404 error.  I don't think m(any) browsers try to load the next video format in the sources if it is compatible with one already.

But, if that is not the case you could try one source at a time and observe the results.

Comment: i thought iOS does .mp4 and not .webM?

Comment: I would have to experiment to find out for sure, but I would think most modern browsers/iOS would support .mp4.  So I would try leaving out the other 2 source tags (perhaps it weighs the formats and picks it's favorite? I doubt that though.) I could also be quiet until someone with an apple product can be of more practical help ^.^;

Comment: yeah, i was pretty sure mp4 is what iOS likes, there is something weird going on since i've pretty much taken the example verbatim from something that works on iOS: http://www.inwebson.com/html5/custom-html5-video-controls-with-jquery/ the only thing that is different is that i've moved the video files into my own folders. Though my code works on chrome